# Runtime synchronization failed in MobileFirst 7.1 on Bluemix container with cloudant noSql DB

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, containers, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I followed the tutorial instructions : 
Install MobileFirst Platform Server 7.1 on Bluemix (https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/labs/administrators/7.1/bluemix/)

I used Cloudant NoSQL DB as database.
It works well for several days.

But after a weekend without use, it doesn't work and i have this message on MobileFirst Operations console: Runtime synchronization failed.

[console message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVHeH.png)

I tried to restart the container and the database application server (liberty) but i've always the same message.

I have to remove the container and repeat the whole procedure.
This is the third time it happens.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting JNDI **ibm.worklight.admin.farm.reinitialize** value to **true** in server.xml. This will re-initalize the farm entries in other words it will clear the stale entries when the application crashes.

Reference : [List of JNDI Properties for MFP Administration](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/r_wladmin_jndi_property_list.html)

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are using the Cloudant shared plan. The shared plan response is not guaranteed like the dedicated Plan. To account for this vagarancies, there was a fix released to 7.1 that you should apply that adds the resiliency needed for the non response from the Cloudant shared plan. Pl apply the latest iFix and this should get solved.

Comment: thank you , i have download this version : 7.1.0.0-MFPF-ServerContainer-IF201602291240 from IBM fix central and build a new container.

Comment: @Sébastien the latest iFix with the fix is 7.1.0.0-MFPF-IF201608012314 . Please use this.

Comment: the iFix you mention (7.1.0.0-MFPF-ServerContainer-IF201602291240) does not have the fix for Cloudant connection issues.

Comment: i try to deploy a new container on bluemix with the 7.1.0.0-MFPF-ServerContainer-IF201608012314. But now i have 'Failed request: /worklightconsole/services/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/spgMobApp' and 'Error message: FWLSE3000E: A server error was detected.' in my firebug console.